# Parse any date with timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, date, parsing

I have been looking for existing solutions, but haven't found something that can handle scenarios like this: I want to be able to parse potentially malformed dates. These dates are being scraped from web pages across the globe, and unfortunately only half of them were kind of enough to provide properly formatted ISO strings.

For the following examples, is my only option to parse the input with regex and then reconstruct the date?

```js
// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21, 2023,06:51 pm EDT');

// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21, 2023 06:51pm EDT');

// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21, 2023 06:51 p.m EDT');

// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21, 2023 06.51 pm EDT'); 

// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21, 2023 06:51 pm ET'); 

// invalid date
new Date('06:51 pm Apr 21, 2023 EDT'); 

// invalid date
new Date('Apr 21st 2023 EDT'); 

// invalid date
new Date('7th Feb 2023');

// invalid date
new Date('3 hours ago');

// invalid date
new Date('10m ago');

// invalid date (haven't solved this one yet)
new Date('Thursday 10:30PM EST');
```

My current solution is to first check the string for date digits + optional timezone, then time digits + optional timezone and finally reconstruct the date string in ISO format. This seems like a lot of boiler plate for what seems like a very common requirement. Is there a simpler approach to the following, which does what want?

```js
import ms from 'ms';

export const TIME_EXPR = /(\d\d?)\s*(a\.?m\.?|p\.?m\.?)|(\d\d?)[.:](\d\d?)(?:[.:](\d\d?))?(?:\s*(a\.?m\.?|p\.?m\.?))?(?:.*(?:\s*(ACDT|ACS?T|AES?T|AKDT|AKS?T|BS?T|CES?T|CDT|CS?T|EDT|ES?T|IS?T|JS?T|MDT|MSK|NZS?T|PDT|PS?T|UTC)))?/i;

export const DATE_EXPR = /(\d\d?\s*(?:h|h(?:ou)?rs?|m|min(?:ute)s?))\s*ago|(?:(\d\d?)([-./])(\d\d?)\3(\d{4}|\d{2})|(\d{4})([-./])(\d\d?)\7(\d\d?)|(?:(\d\d?)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s*)?(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)(?:\s+(\d\d?)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)?(?:[,\s]\s*(\d{4})?))(?:.*(?:\s*(ACDT|ACS?T|AES?T|AKDT|AKS?T|BS?T|CES?T|CDT|CS?T|EDT|ES?T|IS?T|JS?T|MDT|MSK|NZS?T|PDT|PS?T|UTC)))?|(\d\d\d\d+)/i;

export function monthToString(month: number | string) {
  const m = parseInt(`${month}`);
  if (Number.isNaN(m)) {
    return month;
  }
  return new Date(`2023-${m}-07`).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
}

export function parseDate(context?: string) {
  if (!context) {
    return new Date('invalid');
  }
  const date = new Date(context.trim());
  if (!Number.isNaN(date.valueOf()) && date.valueOf() > 0) {
    return date;
  }
  const dateMatches = context.match(DATE_EXPR);
  const timeMatches = context.match(TIME_EXPR);
  let year = String(new Date().getFullYear());
  let month = monthToString(new Date().getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(new Date().getDate());
  let hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0, amOrPm = '';
  let timezone = '';
  if (!dateMatches) {
    return new Date('invalid');
  }
  const [_0, relative, month1, _3, day1, year1, year2, _7, month2, day2, day3, month3, day4, year3, tz = '', timestamp] = dateMatches;
  if (relative) {
    return new Date(Date.now() - ms(relative.replace(/h(?:ou)?rs?/, 'h').replace(/m(?:in)?s?/, 'm')));
  }
  const datetime = parseInt(timestamp);
  if (!Number.isNaN(datetime)) {
    if (!Number.isNaN(new Date(datetime)).valueOf()) {
      return new Date(datetime);
    }
  }
  timezone = tz;
  year = year1 ?? year2 ?? year3 ?? String(new Date().getFullYear());
  month = monthToString(month1 ?? month2 ?? month3 ?? new Date().getMonth() + 1);
  day = day1 ?? day2 ?? day3 ?? day4 ?? String(new Date().getDate());
  if (timeMatches) {
    const [_0, hour1, amOrPm1, hour2, min1, sec1, amOrPm2, timezone2] = timeMatches;
    hour = !Number.isNaN(parseInt(hour1 ?? hour2)) ? parseInt(hour1 ?? hour2) : 0;
    min = !Number.isNaN(parseInt(min1)) ? parseInt(min1) : 0;
    sec = !Number.isNaN(parseInt(sec1)) ? parseInt(sec1) : 0;
    amOrPm = (amOrPm1 ?? amOrPm2 ?? '').replace(/\./g, '');
    if (timezone2) {
      timezone = timezone2;
    }
  }
  const dateMatch = [`${month} ${day}, ${String(year).length === 2 ? `20${year}` : year} ${hour}:${min}:${sec} ${amOrPm ? amOrPm : (hour < 12) ? 'am' : 'pm'}`, timezone.replace(/^(A[CEK]|CE|NZ|[BCEIJP])T$/, ($0, $1) => `${$1}ST`)].join(' ');
  const parsedDate = new Date(dateMatch);
  return parsedDate;
}

export function sortDates(...dates: Date[]) {
  return [...dates].filter((d) => !Number.isNaN(d.valueOf())).sort((a, b) => { 
    return a.valueOf() - b.valueOf();
  });
}

export function minDate(...dates: Date[]) {
  const sortedDates = sortDates(...dates);
  if (sortedDates.length === 0) {
    return new Date('invalid');
  }
  return sortedDates[0];
}

export function maxDate(...dates: Date[]) {
  const sortedDates = sortDates(...dates);
  if (sortedDates.length === 0) {
    return new Date('invalid');
  }
  return sortedDates[sortedDates.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: JavaScript only recognizes ISO standard dates. Different implementations also parse other formats, but it's the luck of the draw. Use a library or write your own date format parser.

Comment: "I cannot even find a node library that can handle scenarios like this" - what did you try?

Comment: I would try to fix it where the malformed dates are produced.

Comment: There are lots of date handling libraries. Luxon is a great current pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to have the date formatted in a standard way (ECMAScript's [Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format)) at the source. If not possible, then indeed you'll need to parse the input (or have a library do that for you).

> I have a super complicated regex ...

Maybe you can build it up in steps, so it stays manageable? Or -- if you decided to have the regex perform numerical validations -- you could drop those validations and leave that for the Date constructor to deal with.

Here is a possible implementation with following characteristics:

- Does not focus on validation; it generously matches numbers that are out of range.
- Allows any punctuation between the components (anything that matches `\W+`)
- Uses a lookup object to map known timezone codes to timezone offsets
- Produces a string that complies with ECMAScript's [Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format) on the condition that the input components were valid (in range).
- Leaves it for the caller to pass that date time string to the date constructor or to `Date.parse`.

```js
const zones = {aoe:'-12:00',y:'-12:00',nut:'-11:00',sst:'-11:00',x:'-11:00',ckt:'-10:00',hst:'-10:00',taht:'-10:00',w:'-10:00',mart:'-09:30',akst:'-09:00',gamt:'-09:00',hdt:'-09:00',v:'-09:00',akdt:'-08:00',pst:'-08:00',pst:'-08:00',u:'-08:00',mst:'-07:00',pdt:'-07:00',t:'-07:00',cst:'-06:00',east:'-06:00',galt:'-06:00',mdt:'-06:00',s:'-06:00',act:'-05:00',cdt:'-05:00',cist:'-05:00',cot:'-05:00',cst:'-05:00',easst:'-05:00',ect:'-05:00',est:'-05:00',pet:'-05:00',r:'-05:00',amt:'-04:00',ast:'-04:00',bot:'-04:00',cdt:'-04:00',cidst:'-04:00',clt:'-04:00',edt:'-04:00',fkt:'-04:00',gyt:'-04:00',pyt:'-04:00',q:'-04:00',vet:'-04:00',nst:'-03:30',adt:'-03:00',amst:'-03:00',art:'-03:00',brt:'-03:00',clst:'-03:00',fkst:'-03:00',gft:'-03:00',p:'-03:00',pmst:'-03:00',pyst:'-03:00',rott:'-03:00',srt:'-03:00',uyt:'-03:00',warst:'-03:00',wgt:'-03:00',ndt:'-02:30',brst:'-02:00',fnt:'-02:00',gst:'-02:00',o:'-02:00',pmdt:'-02:00',uyst:'-02:00',wgst:'-02:00',azot:'-01:00',cvt:'-01:00',egt:'-01:00',n:'-01:00',
    utc:'+00:00',azost:'+00:00',egst:'+00:00',gmt:'+00:00',wet:'+00:00',wt:'+00:00',z:'+00:00',a:'+01:00',bst:'+01:00',cet:'+01:00',ist:'+01:00',wat:'+01:00',west:'+01:00',wst:'+01:00',b:'+02:00',cat:'+02:00',cest:'+02:00',eet:'+02:00',ist:'+02:00',sast:'+02:00',wast:'+02:00',ast:'+03:00',c:'+03:00',eat:'+03:00',eest:'+03:00',fet:'+03:00',idt:'+03:00',msk:'+03:00',syot:'+03:00',trt:'+03:00',irst:'+03:30',adt:'+04:00',amt:'+04:00',azt:'+04:00',d:'+04:00',get:'+04:00',gst:'+04:00',kuyt:'+04:00',msd:'+04:00',mut:'+04:00',ret:'+04:00',samt:'+04:00',sct:'+04:00',aft:'+04:30',irdt:'+04:30',amst:'+05:00',aqtt:'+05:00',azst:'+05:00',e:'+05:00',mawt:'+05:00',mvt:'+05:00',orat:'+05:00',pkt:'+05:00',tft:'+05:00',tjt:'+05:00',tmt:'+05:00',uzt:'+05:00',yekt:'+05:00',ist:'+05:30',npt:'+05:45',
    almt:'+06:00',bst:'+06:00',btt:'+06:00',f:'+06:00',iot:'+06:00',kgt:'+06:00',omst:'+06:00',qyzt:'+06:00',vost:'+06:00',yekst:'+06:00',cct:'+06:30',mmt:'+06:30',cxt:'+07:00',davt:'+07:00',g:'+07:00',hovt:'+07:00',ict:'+07:00',krat:'+07:00',novst:'+07:00',novt:'+07:00',omsst:'+07:00',wib:'+07:00',awst:'+08:00',bnt:'+08:00',cast:'+08:00',chot:'+08:00',cst:'+08:00',h:'+08:00',hkt:'+08:00',hovst:'+08:00',irkt:'+08:00',krast:'+08:00',myt:'+08:00',pht:'+08:00',sgt:'+08:00',ulat:'+08:00',wita:'+08:00',pyt:'+08:30',acwst:'+08:45',awdt:'+09:00',chost:'+09:00',i:'+09:00',irkst:'+09:00',jst:'+09:00',kst:'+09:00',pwt:'+09:00',tlt:'+09:00',ulast:'+09:00',wit:'+09:00',yakt:'+09:00',acst:'+09:30',aest:'+10:00',chut:'+10:00',chst:'+10:00',ddut:'+10:00',k:'+10:00',pgt:'+10:00',vlat:'+10:00',yakst:'+10:00',yapt:'+10:00',acdt:'+10:30',lhst:'+10:30',aedt:'+11:00',bst:'+11:00',kost:'+11:00',l:'+11:00',lhdt:'+11:00',magt:'+11:00',nct:'+11:00',nft:'+11:00',pont:'+11:00',sakt:'+11:00',sbt:'+11:00',sret:'+11:00',vlast:'+11:00',vut:'+11:00',anast:'+12:00',anat:'+12:00',fjt:'+12:00',gilt:'+12:00',m:'+12:00',magst:'+12:00',mht:'+12:00',nfdt:'+12:00',nrt:'+12:00',nzst:'+12:00',petst:'+12:00',pett:'+12:00',tvt:'+12:00',wakt:'+12:00',wft:'+12:00',chast:'+12:45',fjst:'+13:00',nzdt:'+13:00',phot:'+13:00',tkt:'+13:00',tot:'+13:00',wst:'+13:00',chadt:'+13:45',lint:'+14:00',tost:'+14:00'};
const monthRe = "(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)";
const dayRe = "(\\d\\d?)[stnrdh]{0,2}";
const dateRe = `(?:${monthRe}\\W+${dayRe}|${dayRe}\\W+${monthRe})\\W+(\\d{4})`;
const timeRe = "(\\d\\d?):(\\d\\d)(?:\\W*([ap])\\.?m)?(?:\\W*([a-z]{1,5}))?";
const regex = RegExp(`^\\W*${dateRe}(?:\\W+${timeRe})?\\W*$`, "i");

function toDateTimeStringFormat(s) {
    const match = s.toLowerCase().match(regex);
    if (!match) return;
    let [, m1, day, d2, m2, year, hour, minute, pm, zone] = match;
    const month = 1 + (monthRe.indexOf(m1 ?? m2) >> 2); // month name to number
    day ??= d2;
    zone = zones[zone] ?? ""; // timezone code to offset
    hour ??= "0";
    minute ??= "0";
    if (pm) hour = String((+hour % 12) + 12 * (pm == "p")); // to 24h range
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}${zone}`
           .replace(/(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)/g, "0$&"); // pad single digit numbers
}

const tests = [
    'Apr 21, 2023,06:51 pm EDT',
    'Apr 21, 2023 06:51pm EDT',
    'Apr 21, 2023 06:51 pm EDT',
    '7th Feb 2023',
    'Dec 6th, 2022 19:56 CET',
    'Jan 3rd, 2021; 0:04(IST)',
];

for (const test of tests) console.log(toDateTimeStringFormat(test));
```

Of course, this is limited, and would need extension if more input formats need to be supported.

Comment: Yea i went with a custom implementation. Not preferred but it does what I need

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-date-parser ?

> Parse a wide range of date formats including human-input dates.
>
> any-date-parser has an addFormat() function to add a custom parser.
>
> Supported formats
> 24 hour time
> 12 hour time
> timezone offsets
> timezone abbreviations
> year month day
> year monthname day
> month day year
> monthname day year
> day month year
> day monthname year
> +/-/ago periods
> now/today/yesterday/tomorrow
> Twitter

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.